# Generating fast JSON by EditableText Fields

Tags: android, forms, attributes

I would like to create something similar to Inputs of HTML form. Each input has a name and value attribute which is nicely playing together.

However so far I have just found `android:tag` which might be utilized as name attribute of inputs.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/passwordEdit"
     android:tag="name"
     android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```

Simply what I would like to create is building a JSON Object by only EditText's as this:

`jsonObject.put(editableField.getXXX, editableField.getText())`

Please note that the point is here just using layout files in order to build a JSON Object.

Are there any convention for such kind of usage or another appropriate attribute for storing dummy values?

Thanks

Comment: What about View.getTag() ? :)

Comment: I am already using getTag method but thought that there is a better alternative.